# Create table using HTML in Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

i want to know services stopped and which are set to automatic and output file goes to HTML page. In that HTML output i want to create table for stopped services on top of that table server name. Can someone tell me..

```
$ServerListFile = "C:\Dv\Server_List.txt" 
$ServerList = Get-Content $ServerListFile -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
foreach ($Computername in $ServerList) {
Write-Host "Automatic Services Stopped :" $Computername 
Get-wmiobject win32_service -computername $Computername  -Filter  "startmode  
= 'auto'  AND state != 'running'" | Select DisplayName,Name,State,startmode  
|  Format-Table  -auto | Out-File C:\Dv\Report.html
}
```

Comment: Use `ConvertTo-Html`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this should work.

**Single table**

```
Get-Content "C:\Dv\Server_List.txt" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | ForEach-Object {
    Write-Host "Automatic Services Stopped :" $_ 
    Get-WmiObject Win32_Service -ComputerName $_ -Filter  "startmode = 'auto' AND state != 'running'"
} |
    Select-Object DisplayName, Name, State, StartMode |
    ConvertTo-Html |
    Out-File C:\Dv\Report.html
```

**Multiple tables**

This version creates a sequence of tables using `ConvertTo-Html -Fragment`. Each table is preceded by a HTML header (h2 in the example) with the computer name. The individual tables are concatenated and merged into a single HTML document at the end using a bare (no input) call to `ConvertTo-Html`.

```
# Generate the content which should be inserted as a set of HTML tables
$preContent = Get-Content "C:\Dv\Server_List.txt" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | ForEach-Object {
    $ComputerName = $_

    Write-Host "Automatic Services Stopped :" $ComputerName 

    # A table (and heading) will only be generated for $ComputerName if there are services matching the filter. 
    Get-WmiObject Win32_Service -ComputerName $ComputerName -Filter  "startmode = 'auto' AND state != 'running'" |
        Select-Object DisplayName, Name, State, StartMode |
        ConvertTo-Html -PreContent "<h2>$ComputerName</h2>" -Fragment
}

# Generate the document which holds all of the individual tables.
$htmlDocument = ConvertTo-Html -Head $htmlHead -PreContent $preContent | Out-String
# Because the document has no input object it will have an empty table (<table></table>), this should be removed.
$htmlDocument -replace '<table>\r?\n</table>' | Out-File C:\Dv\Report.html
```

**Styling**

You'll find the HTML generated by these to be pretty raw. One of the better ways to tackle that is to use CSS, here's a fragment of mine that makes HTML tables look prettier:

```
$HtmlHead = '<style>
    body {
        background-color: white;
        font-family:      "Calibri";
    }

    table {
        border-width:     1px;
        border-style:     solid;
        border-color:     black;
        border-collapse:  collapse;
        width:            100%;
    }

    th {
        border-width:     1px;
        padding:          5px;
        border-style:     solid;
        border-color:     black;
        background-color: #98C6F3;
    }

    td {
        border-width:     1px;
        padding:          5px;
        border-style:     solid;
        border-color:     black;
        background-color: White;
    }

    tr {
        text-align:       left;
    }
</style>'

# Use the Head parameter when calling ConvertTo-Html
... | ConvertTo-Html -Head $HtmlHead | ...
```

Note: The Head only applies when the Fragment parameter is **not** supplied with ConvertTo-Html.

Comment: Thanks Chris :) Its working.. can you tell me how to print Computer name on top of Table.

Comment: Are you wanting one table per computer (with the computer as a title)? If so, it has to change a little to make that feasible.

Comment: Yes Chris, Script will run for Multiple Servers so i need one table for each Server services and server name on top of table.

Comment: Got it. Editing post above, it's a bit longer. One tick.

Comment: Got it..Thanks Chris