# Create HTML table in email body using powershell

Tags: html, powershell

I am not good at html
I am trying to create a table in outlook email like below (without colors)

[image]

I tried below code but not able to get this format

```
$HtmlTable = "<table border='1' align='Left' cellpadding='2' cellspacing='0' style='color:black;font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;text-align:left;'>
<tr style ='font-size:12px;font-weight: normal;background: #FFFFFF'>
<th align=left><b>Customer Name*</b></th>
<th align=left><b>SERVER NAME</b></th>
<th align=left><b>IP Address</b></th>
<th align=left><b>Hostname without FQDN</b></th>
<th align=left><b>Server OS flavour (Drop Down)</b></th>
<th align=left><b>Datacenter</b></th>


</tr>"

    $HtmlTable += "<tr style='font-size:12px;background-color:#FFFFFF'>
    <td>" + "MYCOMPANY" + "</td>
    <td>" + "TESTSERVER" + "</td>
    <td>" + "10.10.10.10" + "</td>
    <td>" + "test" + "</td>
    <td>" + "test1" + "</td>
    <td>" + "test2" + "</td>
    </tr>"


$HtmlTable += "</table>"

Send-MailMessage -from $fromEmail -to $toEmail -Cc $toCCmail1 -SmtpServer $smtpServer -Body $HtmlTable  -Subject "  Report" -BodyAsHtml
```

Output in email

[image]

the data I have like below

```
$VM = get-vm | where {($_.Name -match $hostname)} | SELECT -Unique
$Summary = $VM | select  @{N="DNSName";E={$_.ExtensionData.Guest.Hostname}}, @{N="IPAddress";E={$_.Guest.IPAddress[0]}}, @{N=”Datacenter”;E={Get-Datacenter -VM $_}}
$DNS = $Summary.DNSName
$pos = $DNS.IndexOf(".")
$DNSName = $DNS.Substring(0, $pos)
$GuestOS = $VM.Guest.OSFullName
$IPAddress = $Summary.IPAddress
$dc = $Summary.Datacenter
```

Please need your help to get this html format

With respect to the solution provided by @Theo

[image]

email body

```
$body = @"

<html>

Hi Team, <br /><br />

Please raise a ticket CPU & memory situation from below servers. <br /><br />

<b>Unmapp (Remove) below Situations -</b><br />

MEMORY_USED_WARN<br />
MEMORY_USED_CRIT<br />
CPU_Warning<br />
    

<br /><br />

$htmlTemplate -replace '@@TABLES@@', ($tables -join '<br />')


Thank you <br /><br />

***This is an auto-generated email. Please do not respond***

</html>

"@
```

Comment: Without an example representation of how the PowerShell objects you want to export to HTML look like is hard to help as we would be guessing for a proper answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this question is all about HTML styling, I would use Here-String templates with placeholder strings to build the body:

```
# the first one is the template for the completed body:
$htmlTemplate = @"
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
    <style>
        body {font-family: Calibri, Tahoma, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: black;}
        table {border-width: 1px; border-style: solid; border-color: black; border-collapse: collapse;width: 100%;}
        td {border-width: 1px; padding: 3px; border-style: solid; border-color: black;}
    </style>
 </head>
 <body>
@@TABLES@@
 </body>
</html>
"@

# the second one is for each table you want to put in
$tableTemplate = @"
  <table>
  <tr>
    <td>Customer Name</td>
    <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center">@@CUSTOMER@@</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="4" style="text-align:center">@@SERVER@@</td>
    <td>IP Address</td></td>
    <td style="text-align:center">@@IP@@</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Hostname without FQDN</td>
    <td style="text-align:center">@@HOSTNAME@@</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Server OS flavour (Drop Down)</td>
    <td style="text-align:center">@@OS@@</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Datacenter</td>
    <td style="text-align:center">@@DATACENTER@@</td>
  </tr>
  </table>
"@
```

Now you use your code to get the info for each VM and loop over that data.
For each of the VM's, you create a table using the $tableTemplate:

```
$tables = foreach ($machine in $VMs) {
    # here your code to gather the data

    # now replace the placeholders in the template with real data and output
    # a completed html table. These will be collected in variable $tables
    $tableTemplate -replace '@@CUSTOMER@@', "YourCustomerName" -replace
                            '@@SERVER@@', "YourServerName" -replace
                            '@@IP@@', $IPAddress -replace
                            '@@HOSTNAME@@', $DNSName -replace
                            '@@OS@@', $GuestOS -replace
                            '@@DATACENTER@@', $dc
}
```

After that, combine this into the completed body:

```
$body = $htmlTemplate -replace '@@TABLES@@', ($tables -join '<br />')
```

and use for the `-Body` parameter in the Send-MailMessage call

You should now have html looking like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this. it's great. Just one thing. when I am getting the output in email, above and below the table I am getting some texts. I have added the screenshot. can you please check.

Comment: @EmptyCoder You did put the line `$body = $htmlTemplate -replace '@@TABLES@@', ,..` **below** the loop and just **before** the Send-MailMessage did you?

Comment: @EmptyCoder ..and the line `$body = $htmlTemplate -replace ...` is one line. It looks like you added a newline before `-replace` ??

Comment: I have other contents in email body. so I have placed the line inside the body. added the email body for your reference. and It will be for individual VM. so removed the loop also.

Comment: I just kept `$htmlTemplate $tables ` in place of `$htmlTemplate -replace '@@TABLES@@', ($tables -join '<br />')` and it worked fine. thanks a ton.

Comment: @EmptyCoder Ah, i thought you needed to loop over a series of VMs, so I 'invented' that loop. Thanks for the nice feedback!

Answer (score 0):

There was the same question asked before, but I won't ask to archive it, 'cause your context of the text is different, so here we are.

I cannot help you right now, but I'll give you enough useful links you can use.

Here:

- https://adamtheautomator.com/html-report/
- [Create table using HTML in Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38991984/create-table-using-html-in-powershell#38992621)
- Even google something like "html table using PowerShell"

If that **doesn't** work, then try this:
**(NOTE: I USED THE SAME QUESTIONS' ANSWER AS REFERENCE)**

**FOR ONE TABLE**

```
Get-Content "C:\Dv\Server_List.txt" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | ForEach-Object {
    Write-Host "Automatic Services Stopped :" $_ 
    Get-WmiObject Win32_Service -ComputerName $_ -Filter  "startmode = 'auto' AND state != 'running'"
} |
    Select-Object DisplayName, Name, State, StartMode |
    ConvertTo-Html |
    Out-File C:\Dv\Report.html
```

**FOR MULTIPLE TABLES**

```
# Generate the content which should be inserted as a set of HTML tables
$preContent = Get-Content "C:\Dv\Server_List.txt" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | ForEach-Object {
    $ComputerName = $_

    Write-Host "Automatic Services Stopped :" $ComputerName 

    # A table (and heading) will only be generated for $ComputerName if there are services matching the filter. 
    Get-WmiObject Win32_Service -ComputerName $ComputerName -Filter  "startmode = 'auto' AND state != 'running'" |
        Select-Object DisplayName, Name, State, StartMode |
        ConvertTo-Html -PreContent "<h2>$ComputerName</h2>" -Fragment
}

# Generate the document which holds all of the individual tables.
$htmlDocument = ConvertTo-Html -Head $htmlHead -PreContent $preContent | Out-String
# Because the document has no input object it will have an empty table (<table></table>), this should be removed.
$htmlDocument -replace '<table>\r?\n</table>' | Out-File C:\Dv\Report.html
```

Even the **STYLING**

```
$HtmlHead = '<style>
    body {
        background-color: white;
        font-family:      "Calibri";
    }

    table {
        border-width:     1px;
        border-style:     solid;
        border-color:     black;
        border-collapse:  collapse;
        width:            100%;
    }

    th {
        border-width:     1px;
        padding:          5px;
        border-style:     solid;
        border-color:     black;
        background-color: #98C6F3;
    }

    td {
        border-width:     1px;
        padding:          5px;
        border-style:     solid;
        border-color:     black;
        background-color: White;
    }

    tr {
        text-align:       left;
    }
</style>

# Use the Head parameter when calling ConvertTo-Html
| ConvertTo-Html -Head $HtmlHead |
```